# Find unused cases of an enum (Objective-C / Swift)

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, find

We’ve just migrated a couple of thousand localised strings in an iOS project from an old `struct` to an enum. We’d now like to find any which are unused.

I’m looking for a way to find any cases of an `enum` which are not used anywhere within my project, short of searching the project for them one by one.

We have the strings in Objective-C and Swift versions, so either will work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you simply comment out the declaration of the `enum` value and try to compile?

Comment: That’d give me errors everywhere one IS used, so I’d still need to write all of those down, and compare to the list to find those which aren’t – right?

Comment: If you comment out an enum value and get no compile errors then you know it isn't being used.

Comment: Ah, so the opposite approach. Might work, but still more time consuming than I’d hoped. Worth a try, though.

Comment: Do it in batches. Comment out 10 and compile. Look at the errors and see which of the 10 aren't reported. Leave those commented out.

Comment: Mm, it does speed it up a bit, fair play. Feel free to leave an answer if you want the kudos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your only option is to comment out each enum value and see which ones result in an error. The ones that don't aren't being used.

If you have a lot of enum values, comment them out in batches of 10 or 15. Do a compile. Scan the errors and uncomment out the values reported in an error. This leaves the unused enum values commented out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to automate this, recently I was asked to search for unused endpoints in a large project, to make this semi-automatic:

1- run this grep command, to search for **used** endpoints

```
grep -r --include='*.swift' "EndpointEnum"
```

2- use a text editor (I used sublime), to **sort**, make **unique** and save into used.txt

3- add all the enum values in **all.txt**

4- diff between the two files, and keep the lines starting with a "-"

this will give you the unused enum values.